# MySQL Insert from another table with variable increment

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I have two tables in mysql. One called registros_temporal with all columns of registros except one column called id.

I need to insert all rows from registros_temporal into registros and the column id incrementing with a factor.

Structures:

```
registros:
id, fecha, codigos... (50 columns)

registros_temporal
fecha, codigos... (49 columns)
```

My query is

```
SET @mes = 01;
SET @anho = 2016;

SET @id = (@anho-2000)*1000000000 + @mes*10000000;
SELECT @id;

INSERT INTO registros
(
SELECT (@id := @id + 1) AS id, ll.* FROM registros_temporal ll 
ORDER BY fecha ASC
)
;

SELECT (@id := @id + 1) AS id, ll.* FROM registros_temporal ll 
ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```

When the data is load i have an error in id column. All are 2147483647 when i expect 16010000001, 16010000002, 16010000003, 16010000004, ...

Id column is an integer field

Comment: I need the increment exponentially.

Answer (score 4):

2147483647 is the largest int value in MySQL for signed int data type. Initial value 16010000000 is greater than 2147483647.
Change your column type to bigint

Comment: `BIGINT` is correct. `UNSIGNED INT` makes no sense here, why are you even suggesting it?

Comment: @victorzubiaga then you should mark it as the accepted answer, both to give credit where it is due, and to save others time from clicking on your question thinking it still needs an answer.